# sync a particular file recursively but only in the subdirectories present in destination

Tags: rsync, remote, file-copy, synchronization

I have two directories `dirOrig` and `dirDest` in different remote servers. Both of them have numerous subdirectories at various depths. I now need to copy a specific file or extension -- say `file1.txt` recursively from `dirOrig` to `dirDest`. But, I need to copy the file only if the subdirectory is already present in `dirDest`.

For example, I can systematically copy only a specific file from source to destination using rsync using

```
rsync -zarv  --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/"  --include="file1.txt" --exclude="*" "dirOrig" "dirDest"
```

But how to restrict this copy only to the subdirectories present in the destination (`dirDest`)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of a single command, but the hack that I came up with is as follows.

1. Use `rsync` to copy the `dirOrig` from `server1` to `server2`

   `rsync -zarv  --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" \
   --include="file1.txt" --exclude="*" "server1:dirOrig" \
   "server2:dirOrig"`
2. Delete the subdirectories in the copied `dirOrig` that are not present in `dirDest` using `comm`

   `comm -23 <( cd  server2:dirOrig && find -mindepth 1 -type d | sort ) \
   <( cd server2:dirDest && find -mindepth 1 -type d | sort )  \
   | ( cd server2:dirOrig && xargs rm -rf )`
3. Finally rsync the `dirDest` with `dirOrig` based on checksum and delete all files in dirOrig not present in dirDest except for `file1.txt`

   `rsync -acv --exclude=file1.txt --delete \
   server2:dirDest server2:dirOrig`